# Unbind special keypress event

Tags: jquery, keypress, unbind

I've got a question regarding jQuery keypress events. I've got the following (working) code:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {

    if ($('#myDiv').is(':visible')) {

        if (event.which == 102) {
            // ...do something...
        }

    }
    else {
        if (event.which == 102) {
            return;
        }
    }

});
```

I always "unbind" the event with binding another "over" it. I know that I can unbind it with `.unbind('keypress')` but I got more keypress events and when i unbind this with `$(document).unbind('keypress')` all my events get lost.

Can I do something like "keypress.102" to only unbind this particular "key" or how can this be done?!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You were on the right track. That's called [namespaced events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events), i.e. labelling specific bindings using `<event_name>.<namespace>` (in your case, "keypress.102").

For example:

```
$(document).bind("keypress.key102", function(event) {
    if ($('#myDiv').is(':visible')) {

        if (event.which == 102) {
            // ...do something...
        }

    }
    else {
        if (event.which == 102) {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

you can later unbind that without affecting other bound keypress events:

```
$(document).unbind("keypress.key102");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a namespaced event.

http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

Comment: Can you give an example of how the OP should use namespaced events to solve this problem?